# forcing the version of a library's transitive Maven dependencies via the library itself

Tags: java, maven, log4j, dependency-management, maven-bom

I'm familiar with how a Maven project such as `my-app` can force the version of transitive dependencies. Today I stumbled onto a related question: how can a library `my-lib` force the versions of its transitive dependencies in relation to `my-app` without directly including the transitive dependencies?

I have a library `my-lib`, the only purpose of which is to make it easy for other projects to include several transitive dependencies at once—in other words, `my-lib` is sort of like a bundling mechanism. In `my-lib/pom.xml` I duly declare `com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.5.1` and then use it:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But I want to override the version of Log4j being used, so in `my-lib-parent` I import a specific Log4j BOM version:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.20.0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

Sure enough, if I do a `mvn dependency:tree` on `my-lib`, it shows that Log4j 2.20.0 is being used:

```
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
```

So I happily added `my-lib` as a dependency to `my-app`. When my code tried to log information, I got a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/BridgeAware`. It turns out that even though the `my-lib` project is using `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.20.0`, this is only in relation to `my-lib` itself—it doesn't effect the versions of the transitive dependencies `my-lib` brings in, in terms of `my-app`, when `my-app` includes `my-lib` as a dependency!

Thus if I do a `mvn dependency:tree` on `my-app`, it shows that `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1` is being used:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:jar:1.5.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:provided
```

I guess it makes sense, but frankly I had never thought much about it. I had just assumed that `my-app` would get the version of transitive dependencies set by dependency management in `my-lib`.

I note that `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:jar:2.20.0` is getting the right version in `my-app`, which also came in to `my-lib` via the Log4j BOM, but that seems to be because `my-lib` explicitly includes `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:jar:2.20.0` as its direct dependency.

So is that the only solution: am I forced to go find and enumerate all the transitive dependencies of `com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2` and declare them explicitly in `my-lib` if I want them to be set to another version when `my-lib` is included in another project? Is there a simpler approach, similar to importing a BOM, that would allow `my-lib` to simply say "force all transitive Log4j versions to that of the Log4j BOM when `my-lib` is included in another project"?

Comment: I think that `<scope>provided</scope>` is exactly why it goes wrong. It tells Maven to _not_ include it in the application, but as a result, neither are its transitive dependencies.

Comment: No, `<scope>provided</scope>` only changes whether the dependency is included, not what versions are determined. Removing `<scope>provided</scope>` has no effect; I'll take that part out of the question so as not to throw people off track.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled about the problem in the past: DependencyManagement is not transitive.

You can avoid the problem by using the flatten Maven Plugin to produce a "consumer pom".